# RDC into Windows Server 2016 Evaluation Trial

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server-2016

I'm receiving the following error when trying to RDC into a Windows Server 2016 Eval box from a local Windows 10 Pro laptop:

> An authentication error has occurred.
> The function request is not supported
>
> Remote computer: 192.169.x.x
> This could be due to CredSSP encryption
> oracle remediation. For more information, see
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=866660

[Error Box Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfgdI.png)

I've opened up the appropriate ICMP4 and File/Printer Sharing firewall rules to successfully ping the target machine, map a network drive from the local laptop to the target machine's c$ directory, and lastly I've enabled remote desktop through the target machine's Server Manager. Also confirmed the remote desktop rules with the following Powershell cmd:

```
Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup *remote*desktop* | FT
```

All three rules are enabled... What am I missing?

Could it be related to:

- The target machine is eval software?
- Group Policy related? Specifically... This testing is being done in my home network (a non AD domain). The **target machine** is native to my **home** network, but the *local laptop* connecting to the **target machine** is a *domain device native to my employer's domain*... again, connecting to the **target** in my **home** network. ie... must I make the target server trust my company's domain since the two machines might be in different domains, even in my home network? Pardon my ignorance on this topic... could be completely unrelated, but my limited knowledge of identity and security in Windows makes me think it might be worth it to ask. If so, what are my options?

Again, (1) pings and (2) file-explorer-connectivity work just fine in this configuration, but (3) RDCs don't.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you do the obvious: install the updates?

Comment: Did you bother to read the linked article in the error message? I mean... it's kind of obvious... staring at you right in the face... with a link and everything... it couldn't be any easier than that could it?

Comment: Thought I did. Was obviously mistaken since updates corrected the issue. Pardon the false alarm and the rookie mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the server is vulnerable to the oracle encryption bug.  You have 2 options to fix this issue.

1) Update the server via windows update to all the latest updates.

2) Follow the directions [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mckittrick/unable-to-rdp-to-virtual-machine-credssp-encryption-oracle-remediation/) to modify the security settings on your machine (or the machine you are RDPing from)

Comment: Thanks, Joe. I thought I had already installed the latest updates but must have been mistaken. Simply installing updates solved the issue. Pardon the rookie mistake and the late reply.